# Is $E = p^0$ in non-inertial frames?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, energy, momentum

In special relativity the energy of a particle is the 0-component of the 4-momentum. However, is this still true in non-inertial frames, and in particular in non-freely-falling frames in general relativity? Can you derive this, if it is still true? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "energy" in general relativity?

Comment: I appreciate that there is some ambiguity when it comes to defining the energy of the gravitational field, and that energy conservation in GR is not just the statement that 'the total energy is constant', but the notion of the energy of a particle still exists. Indeed, my question is really the question you've just asked!

Answer (score 0):

A test particle in general relativity moves along a worldline. If the world line is differentiable, then it has a tangent. If the test particle is similar to a massive particle, that worldline has tangents that are always timelike. And you could make a unit tangent.

That unit tangent lives in the 4d tangent space. As does the energy-momentum vector. In fact, they are proportional. And you can multiply the unit tangent by the rest mass and you get the entire energy-momentum vector.

No frame needed. Frames are only needed if you like to talk about components of vectors instead of vectors. In this case the orthogonal component of the energy-momentum vector in the direction of itself (i.e. the unit tangent, which since it is unit, is a direction) is the mass or the rest energy. And obviously you could express the vector in any basis you want.

Or just use the vector as a vector.

Comment: Yes, but I'm explicitly interested here in the components, not the abstract 4-vector itself. I want to know how I extract the energy of a particle from its 4-momentum, if I'm measuring the energy in a particular frame of reference.